# How to set default nice value for a particular program?

Tags: 16.04, cpu, process, top, nice

Whenever I want to launch a program with a custom priority level, I have to type `$nice -5 <Program>` in the terminal. 
I want to set the custom priority level to particular program as default priority level. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to launch a program with a non-default priority. You can set a non-default priority on programs running under a specific user, or even group, but that is probably not what you want.

One trick would be to use an alias:

```
alias myprioprogram='nice -10 myprogram'
```

Now, if you launch `myprioprogram` it will actually run `myprogram` with a lower priority.